# Combine lists of dictionaries from rows and then extract strings from it to form a new row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a dataframe and one of the columns has a combination of data types, list, dictionary, and missing value like this:

```
df['category']

0 [{'id': '3120', 'name': '1109 Neurosciences'}, {'id': '2019', 'name': '1344 Statistics'}]
1 [{'id': '9572', 'name': '1234 Mathematics'}, {'id': '2345', 'name': '1307 Biology'}, {'id': '3456', 'name': '9876 Computer Science'}]
2 NaN
3 [{'id': '2378', 'name': '1398 Computer Vision'}]
```

I would like to combine all the rows together and make it a new row, and if possible only a portion of the data.

The output would be like:

```
df_new['category']

0 [Neurosciences, Statistics, Mathematics, Biology, Computer Science, Computer Vision]
```

Thank yall so much!

Comment: why everything is put to row `0`?

Comment: I'm assuming you just want a list of the names?  Not necessarily a new dataframe?

Comment: @Chris I have more columns similar to this but those are just regular list in a cell. The idea is to turn entire df to just one row of data, and each cell would be a list, if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use df.explode() in pandas > 0.25.

```
df = df.dropna()
df = df.explode('cat')
df['cat'] = df['cat'].str.get('name').str.split().str[1]
df.index = len(df)*[0]
df = df.groupby(df.index)[['cat']].agg(' '.join)
print(df)

                                                 cat
0  Neurosciences Statistics Mathematics Biology C...
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
import itertools

def extract_name(l):
    try:
        return [''.join([i for i in _['name'] if not i.isdigit()]).strip() for _ in l] 
    except:
        return 

# apply the extract_name function and convert output to list
classes = df['category'].apply(extract_name).dropna().values.tolist()

# flatten the list
[*itertools.chain(*classes)]
```

Output:

```
['Neurosciences',
 'Statistics',
 'Mathematics',
 'Biology',
 'Computer Science',
 'Computer Vision']
```

Comment: are there any differences between list with single quotation marks around each string and without?

Comment: Single quotes and double quotes are interchangeable, except for stylistic preferences. A string must be defined using either single or double quotes.

Comment: Similarly, for a list of strings, each will be wrapped in single or double quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [{'id': '3120', 'name': '1109 Neurosciences'}, {'id': '2019', 'name': '1344 Statistics'}],
    [{'id': '9572', 'name': '1234 Mathematics'}, {'id': '2345', 'name': '1307 Biology'}, {'id': '3456', 'name': '9876 Computer Science'}],
    [np.nan],
    [{'id': '2378', 'name': '1398 Computer Vision'}]
    ]

global newrow
newrow = []

def parse(row):
    blacklist = ["id", "name","nan", "dtype", "object", "none"]
    s = str(row)
    s = ''.join(c for c in s if c not in "0123456789:,'{}")
    s = ' '.join([w for w in s.split() if w.lower() not in blacklist])
    [newrow.append(i) for i in s.split()]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.apply(lambda row: parse(row) )
df_new = pd.DataFrame([newrow])
print(df_new)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Neurosciences',
 'Statistics',
 'Mathematics',
 'Biology',
 'Computer Science',
 'Computer Vision']
```